# Can't get the Rest Post response in Jquery Ajax post call

Tags: java, jquery, ajax, web-services, rest

I am calling the Rest call using the Ajax post method but i get the below error or response.

```
{"readyState":0,"status":0,"statusText":"error"}
```

Even i enable the cors($.support.cors = true; ) and crossDomain (crossDomain: true (add in headers)).

Here is the sample request:-

```js
function() {
        $.support.cors = true;         
        var evergentData = {
        "UpdateContactRequestMessage":{
         "channelPartnerID":"123456",
       "email":"greg@gmail.com",
       "firstName":"greg",
       "lastName":"chappel",
       "externalId":"GC123",
       "sessionToken":"f53095854bb230996f54fe32ed5a63f68c7718c7"
        }
      };
      
      //GetProducts();
      
      jQuery.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'url for rest api call',
        contentType: "application/json",
        Accept: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: 'json',
        data: evergentData,
        //data: JSON.stringify(evergentData),
        crossDomain: true,
        processData: true,
        headers: { 'access-control-allow-origin': '*',
        },
         success: function(resp){  
             // we have the response  
             alert("Server said123:\n '" + resp + "'");  
           },  
           error: function(e){  
             alert('Error121212: ' + e);  
             alert(e.toString());
             console.log('my message' + e);
             console.log('tables: ' + JSON.stringify(e));
           } 
           
          
      });
    };
```

But i tested this Restapi call in the 'postman' google chrome extension i got the response(successfully got the response).

Here is the response headers:-

```
access-control-allow-headers → client_type, content-type, accept, accept-language, auth_token_base64, appID, accept-encoding, content-length, x-requested-with
```

access-control-allow-methods → POST, GET, OPTIONS, DELETE

access-control-allow-origin → *

allow → GET, HEAD, POST, PUT, DELETE, TRACE, OPTIONS

content-length → 92

content-type → application/json

x-frame-options → sameorigin

x-webobjects-loadaverage → 0

Anyone help me why i didn't get response from rest api call in JqueryAjax post calls.

Thank's advance.

Comment: Change this `data: evergentData` to `data: JSON.stringify(evergentData)`

Comment: I already do that but no use....

Comment: In firebug shows the
Like this
Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at URL. This can be fixed by moving the resource to the same domain or enabling CORS.

and error response is 

{"readyState":0,"status":0,"statusText":"error"}

Answer (score 0):

It is important to understand that `access-control-allow-origin': '*'` in REQUEST header does nothing.

The `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header must be in the RESPONSE header of the service you are calling. So the service regulates who is allowed to call the resource, thus service must add your app URL to it's RESPONSE `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header.

Also note that wildcard * does not work for resources accessed over HTTPS. For resources over HTTPS ONLY absolute paths are valid.

Why Postman works? Cause it ignores the headers and policies while browser does not.

More reading:

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS

Comment: i am testing both http and https rest api call's facing the same problem.

In response add these headers


 response.setHeader("client_type, content-type, accept, accept-language, auth_token_base64, appID, accept-encoding, content-length, x-requested-with","Access-Control-Allow-Headers");

  response.setHeader("*","Access-Control-Allow-Origin");

  response.setHeader("GET, HEAD, POST, PUT, DELETE, TRACE, OPTIONS","Allow");

  response.setHeader("POST, GET, OPTIONS, DELETE", "Access-Control-Allow-Methods");

Comment: In access-control-allow-origin i replace with my local url also not working

Comment: @user1931467 POST request should be pre-flighted with OPTIONS request which is automatically done by the browser. Do you see an OPTIONS request to the same service? What is the response to the OPTIONS? Does OPTIONS request have the headers? More info on preflight - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS#Preflighted_requests

Comment: OPTION request,something like
curl "https://192.169.0.188:7001/ev/updateContact" -X OPTIONS -H "Access-Control-Request-Method: POST" -H "Origin: http://192.169.0.229:7002" -H "Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, sdch" -H "Accept-Language: es,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.6,pt;q=0.4" -H "User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/41.0.2272.118 Safari/537.36" -H "Accept: */*" -H "Referer: http://192.169.0.229:7002/profile?__debug__=test-evergent" -H "Connection: keep-alive" -H "DNT: 1" -H "Access-Control-Request-Headers: accept, content-type" --compressed

Comment: Response Like:-
setHeader("text/xml", "content-type");
setHeader("application/json", "content-type");
setHeader("client_type, content-type, accept, accept-language, auth_token_base64, appID, accept-encoding, content-length, x-requested-with","Access-Control-Allow-Headers");
setHeader("*","Access-Control-Allow-Origin");
setHeader("GET, HEAD, POST, PUT, DELETE, TRACE, OPTIONS","Allow");
setHeader("POST, GET, OPTIONS, DELETE", "Access-Control-Allow-Methods");